Forgot to show tracked changes in revised conference paper. Is this a big issue?
Recently submitted to a Computer Science conference where after the rebuttal, they requested a revised pdf that shows the tracked changes when responding to the reviewers. Responded well to the reviewers, made the changes to my pdf, but forgot to highlight those changes in the pdf :(
I'm really nervous on this. Contacted them to ask if they would allow me to send a revised pdf with the tracked changes since I only got it in at the end of last week but haven't heard back yet. How big of an issue will this be? I'm sweating right now. Any thoughts would be very helpful!

The only people that can accurately answer this question are conference organizers and referees.  Any answers you get here will be less than useless, as they can be misleading.

Please do not vandalize your question. Leaving it in this state allows it to be edited and reopened. And sometimes people disagree with the close voters and will vote to reopen even without changes.

This might depend on their general evaluation of your paper and how likely acceptance was prior to this round of edits. It might also depend on both scheduling and on the number and quality of competing papers since time and space is limited at conferences. Likewise, deadlines can be pretty firm. For a journal it probably wouldn't matter.
You were correct to contact them immediately. If you have a channel to send the proper document then do so without waiting for an answer. It can only speed the process which might be necessary.

Impossible to guess. Too many variables.
